# WPF: Why can't I read an attached property from inside a control-template trigger?

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

In WPF, I created a ControlTemplate for a button, and tried to change the Background Brush through a trigger. To store the value of the brush, I use an attached property.

I tested the attached property itself and it works well - it can be set, and it can be bound to (such as when I simply bind the background to that property).

But when I try to get that property inside the trigger (change the Background to the value of that property), the value isn't even read (as I see when I breakpoint inside the attached property getter), and the background changes to transparent.

How can I fix this?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultButtonTemplate"  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Border 
        x:Name="border" 
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        >
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ButtonAttachedProperties.BackgroundOnMouseOver}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It misunderstands you. It thinks you're referencing a property of a property, not a two-part name of one property. Try disambiguating with parens, like this:

```
Path=(myns:ButtonAttachedProperties.BackgroundOnMouseOver)
```

Don't forget the namespace.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!